# if else statment in go lang

Tags: if-statement, go

Could someone help me debug this program, only the else part is processed on every input.
This id a program for grading students. a student inputs a mark and the the grade is displayed

```
func main(){
    var x int
    fmt.Println("Enter your marks")

    fmt.Scanf("%d",&x)

    if (100 <= x) && (x<=75){
        fmt.Println("D1")
    }else if (74 <= x)&&(x <= 70){
        fmt.Println("D2")
    }else if (69 <= x )&&(x<=65){
        fmt.Println("C3")
    }else if (64 <= x)&&(x <= 60){
        fmt.Println("C4")
    }else if (59 <= x)&&(x <= 55){
        fmt.Println("C5")
    }else if (54 <= x)&&( x<= 50){
        fmt.Println("C6")
    }else if (49 <= x )&&(x<= 45){
        fmt.Println("P7")
    }else{
        fmt.Println("Work harder")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have a logic problem.

Change

```
if (100 <= x) && (x<=75){
```

to

```
if 75 <= x && x <= 100 { // numbers here are ordered from smallest to greatest
```

because a number can't be greater than 100 *and* smaller than 75.

And it's the same for the other lines of course.

Note that you could make less comparisons. Suppose you test if the number is smaller than 100 initially, then you don't have to test if it's smaller than 75 just after you tested it's smaller than 75.

A typical Go code would probably have a `switch` here instead of all those `if/else`. See [switch in the documentation](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#switch). Here's how it could be written with a `switch` :

```
switch {
case x > 100:
    fmt.Println("Congrats!") // you forgot this one
case x >= 75:
    fmt.Println("D1")
case x >= 70:
    fmt.Println("D2")
case x >= 65:
    fmt.Println("C3")
case x >= 60:
    fmt.Println("C4")
case x >= 55:
    fmt.Println("C5")
case x >= 50:
    fmt.Println("C6")
case x >= 45:
    fmt.Println("P7")
default:
    fmt.Println("Work harder")
}
```

A last comment : This type of switching code rarely occurs because normally the thresholds and related notes are stored as data, for example in a `struct`.

Comment: Gah! `constant <= variable && variable <= constant` is confusing.

Comment: @BilltheLizard That form of compare mirrors the maths notation `75 <= x <= 100` in which case `75 <= x && x <= 100` makes a lot of sense. It looks much better without all the unnecessary parentheses too!

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood I agree that it makes more sense to write it that way, but my eye isn't used to it so my brain didn't parse it right.  :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Do you like the switch version better ? I guess the reason we're not used to parse those is that we most often have all those threshold in data, not in constants directly in the middle of the code, and we loop...

Comment: Yes, that definitely looks more natural.

Answer (score 1):

Your IF statement says:

```
if 100 is less than x (which means x has to be greater than 100)
AND
x less than (or equal to) 75
do this--
```

x will never be greater than 100 AND less than 75, so it always does the ELSE ...

Answer (score -1):

all if and if else statements provided in this code are logically incorrect

example:

```
 if (100 <= x) && (x<=75)
```

here if (100 <= x) is false, the compiler will not even consider the next condition.
This is called SHORT CIRCUIT, the lazy evaluation of condition statements.

this is also applicable to OR conditions i.e in case the first condition is true the second condition will not be evaluated.

So according to the code you have written, the ideal solution will be

```
func main() {
    var x int
    fmt.Println("Enter your marks")

    fmt.Scanf("%d", &x)

    if (100 >= x) && (x >= 75) {
        fmt.Println("D1")
    } else if (74 >= x) && (x >= 70) {
        fmt.Println("D2")
    } else if (69 >= x) && (x >= 65) {
        fmt.Println("C3")
    } else if (64 >= x) && (x >= 60) {
        fmt.Println("C4")
    } else if (59 >= x) && (x >= 55) {
        fmt.Println("C5")
    } else if (54 >= x) && (x >= 50) {
        fmt.Println("C6")
    } else if (49 >= x) && (x >= 45) {
        fmt.Println("P7")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Work harder")
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Thankx finaly got with your help. hope it helps someone else some time in future

> package main

```
import "fmt"

func main(){
var x int
fmt.Println("Enter your marks")
fmt.Scanf("%d",&x)
if (75<= x) && (x<=100){
      fmt.Println("D1")
      }else if (70 <= x)&&(x <= 74){
       fmt.Println("D2")
      }else if (65 <= x )&&(x<=69){
      fmt.Println("C3")
      }else if (60 <= x)&&(x <= 64){
      fmt.Println("C4")
      }else if (55 <= x)&&(x <= 59){
      fmt.Println("C5")
      }else if (50 <= x)&&( x<= 54){
      fmt.Println("C6")
      }else if (45 <= x )&&(x<= 49){
      fmt.Println("P7")
      }else{
        fmt.Println("Work harder")
      }

      }
```

Comment: As written in another comment. Don't mix `constant <= variable` and `variable <= constant` within the same if-clause. It makes the code less readable, as you have seen.